# when exception occure write it in file using python

Tags: python, try-except

I just wants to write exception details in file: I tried as below"

```
def WriteErrorLog(e) :
   global lcnt

   lstErr=[]

   iUrlfOutputFile = open("C:\Error.log", "a")
   csvUrlfInfoWriter = csv.writer(iUrlfOutputFile,  delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
   exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
   fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
   csvUrlfInfoWriter.writerow('[Exc_Type, FileName, Script_Line No,InputFile_LineNo]')
   lstErr.append(exc_type)
   lstErr.append(fname)
   lstErr.append(g_lcnt)
   for value in lstErr :
       csvUrlfInfoWriter.writerow(value)

   iUrlfOutputFile.close()
```

in except block:

```
 except Exception as e :
        WriteErrorLog(e)
```

Its not working, can someone correct me? or can suggest any better option?
Thanks!!

Comment: format your code please. cant expect us to do that and then fix your code .

Comment: @Srikar Appal : Sorry, Have formatted it now.

Comment: "Is not working" is not an error description.

Comment: @Emma where is `try:`? from where does your `try-except` start and end?

Comment: Where are you using 'e' param in your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Python Loggin -> http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html
You can format its lines to be ',' delimited, for example

```
[formatter_generic_form]
format='%(asctime)s , %(levelname)s , %(message)s'
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Datetime, level_of_log, whatever_message_you_want_to_log

I recommend you http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial to start